# In a tennis tournement of 128 players, elimination system, what is the probability that two twins will meet at some point?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Needs to be solved using conditional probability. I was thinking using the formula for total probability and having the hypothesis $H_i$ - they get to the $i$-th round and ($A$-they meet) $$P(A)=\sum P(A|H_i)P(H_i)$$ I reach a dilemma when trying to find these values, unsure whether to take into account which part of the tournament tree do they meet..  each player has an equal chance of winning.

Comment: How many pairs of twins are playing, and if more than 1, does it matter if the two twins that meet are from the same pair?

Comment: This needs some more assumptions. For example, do you know that all the tennis players are of equal skill? If the twins are always capable of beating everyone else, they're guaranteed to meet each other. If they always lose to everyone else, they're guaranteed not to unless they're paired against each other in round 1.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming everyone's of equal skill and there's uniformly random initial seeding, we can appeal to symmetry:

Suppose there are $2^n$ players.

There are $2^n(2^n-1)/2$ pairs of players.

There are $2^n-1$ matches.

Therefore the probability they meet is $$\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$

Comment: is this supposed to be $\frac{1}{2^{n}-1}$ where the power term in your response should not be n-1 to the power?

Comment: How did you get the probability from the information you proposed??

Answer (score 3):

Hint: What is the probability they need to win $i$ games each to play each other? If they need to win $i$ games each  to play each other what is the probability it happens?